# PHP+ZipArchive+РусскийЯзык=Кракозябры

Tags: php, linux, ziparchive

Здравствуйте. Помогите решить проблему: есть [zip-архив](http://iait.kg/wp-content/plugins/metamaker/packages/308313---16945050_2016_-_2(31).zip) неизвестно где и как созданный, нужно распаковать все файлы во вложенную папку, причем файлы в архиве имеют имена, содержащие русские буквы.
Пробовал [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163173/php-ziparchive-russian-language):

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($uploadfile);
$dir = $uploaddir . basename($uploadfile,".zip");
mkdir($dir);
$zip->extractTo($dir);
$zip->close();
#unlink($uploadfile);
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach ($files as $filename)
{
    print iconv('cp866', 'utf-8', $filename).PHP_EOL;
}
```

В результате вижу [кракозябры](http://iait.kg/wp-content/uploads/2016/308313---16945050_2016_-_2(31)/)...
Пробовал просто переименовать файлы [командой](https://www.opennet.ru/tips/2494_zip_rus_patch.shtml):

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'np=`echo {}|iconv -f cp1252 -t cp850| iconv -f cp866`; mv "{}" "$np"' \;
```

Опять получаются кракозябры...
Однако если напрямую из оболочки через ssh запустить на сервере:

```
unzip -d '308313---16945050_2016_-_2(31)' '308313---16945050_2016_-_2(31).zip'
```

то все распаковывается [нормально](http://iait.kg/wp-content/plugins/metamaker/packages/308313---16945050_2016_-_2(31)/).
Причем, если я выполняю ту же команду через PHP, с помощью system, то опять получаю кракозябры.
Помогите, не могу понять в чем проблема?
На всякий случай некоторая информация о системе, полученная через ssh:

```
$ uname -a
Linux iait-server 4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:58:04 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
$ locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ru_RU:ru
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2):

возможно кому-то как и мне поможет вот этот вариант. вначале сам многое попробовал из разных кодировок в один этап. но при проверке на каком-то ресурсе, несмотря на то что php показывал, что тут utf-8 показало ср437. и когда встретил этот вариант уже был готов что это поможет.

```
$name = iconv('UTF-8', 'cp437//IGNORE', $zip->getNameIndex($i));
$name = iconv('cp437', 'cp865//IGNORE', $name);
$name = iconv('cp866','UTF-8//IGNORE',$name);
```

для подробностей источник результата где сам автор, уважаемый DieZeeL и привел решение. выношу сюда, чтобы увеличить шанс, что его найдут ищущие и его труд не только мне будет полезен. возможно лишнего много написал, но хотел объяснить, что это не просто так вариант и отметить усилия автора.
[PHP Как перекодировать имена файлов с кириллицей при извлечении из zip архива?](https://qna.habr.com/q/546011)

Answer (score 1):

Пока что решил так:

```
        $dir = $uploaddir . basename($uploadfile,".zip");
        mkdir($dir);
        exec("unzip -d '". $dir ."' '".$uploadfile . "'");
        $files = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($files as $filename)
        {
            if ($filename == ".." or $filename==".") continue;
            $newname = iconv('cp866', 'utf-8', $filename);
            rename($dir."/".$filename, $dir."/".$newname);
        }
```

Думаю что unzip должен быть везде, только в какую кодировку переводит ZipArchive имена файлов я так и не разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно перед вызовом кода разархивации установить локаль для PHP в cp866:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.CP866");
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня на практике встречалось существование нескольких разных кодировок в именах файлов внутри Zip архива. Решил так:

```
$fileName = $this->zip->getNameIndex($i, \ZipArchive::FL_ENC_RAW);

        if (!$sourceEncoding = mb_detect_encoding($fileName)) {
            $fileName = iconv('CP866', 'UTF8', $fileName);
        }
```